# How to aggregate field values into array in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

Have lots of documents in ElasticSearch 5.x index:

```
{
  "price": 5.1, 
  "property": 5,
  "key": "some-key1"
},
{
  "price": 7.1, 
  "property": 5,
  "key": "some-key2"
}
```

`price` and `property` are numbers and `key` has `keyword` type in Elastic.

I can easily aggregate them to have a sum of fields `price`, grouped by `property` field.

But I'd like to aggregate `key` values in array grouped by property field as well.

Here's an example:

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "by_property" : {
      "terms": { "field": "property" }
      "aggs": {
        "sum_by_property": {
          "sum" : { "field" : "price" } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return sum of field `price` grouped by field `property`

How to modify the query to make it return `key` values in array? Grouped by field `property` as well:

```
{
  "key": 5,
  "sum_by_property": { "value": 12.2 },
  "keys_array": { "value": ["some-key1", "some-key2"] } //how to get this?
}
```

Comment: Does [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) meet your requirement?

Comment: @ZhitaoYue, `terms aggregation` just adds `GROUP BY` statement, but it doesn't make array from document field values. Or may be I'm doing smth wrong?

Comment: I guess what you want is `DISTINCT`.  If you ignore the count which `GROUP BY` calc out, it gets same results with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @ZhitaoYue, hmm, I don't get you. Could you please show a query sample?

Comment: `{
  "aggs" : {
    "by_property" : {
      "terms": { "field": "property" }
      "aggs": {
        "sum_by_property": {
          "sum" : { "field" : "price" } 
        },
        "all_keys": {
          "term": {"field": "key", "size":2147483647}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks, looks it's exactly what I need! Could you please transform your comment to an answer to make be able to select it as a correct one?